# How to override application.yaml or configmap.yaml dynamically

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, configmap, application.properties

How to override application.yaml or configmap.yaml property values dynamically or during runtime in springboot using java

i am having 3 Boolean flags in application.yaml, by default A1,A2 will be false and i am introducing 3rd Boolean Z.

1st scenario: if ZConnector.isEnable: ture means

A1Connector.isEnable: true
A2Connector.isEnable: false

2nd scenario: if ZConnector.isEnable: false means

A1Connector.isEnable: false
A2Connector.isEnable: true

once the application is started means value should be override in application.yaml or configmap.yaml and maintain override value in full session.

I tried using postconstruct method but the value is not maintained in the session, it is maintained in the implemented class only instead in session.

Comment: So if the values are dynamic why are they in application.yaml at all?

Comment: Not sure if this is the right direction but maybe consider using Spring profiles and annotate accordingly? Wouldn't be "dynamic" but might solve your use case nonetheless.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.